# QGIS error when accessing data from Database via eVis and ODBC

Tags: qgis, odbc

Using the "eVis Database Connection" I can access an ODBC data source which contains records with Lat and Long fields. The connection is made OK, and the "Database File Selection" window opens where I can define the name of the new layer and the x and y coordinate fields. Having done this, clicking OK gives the error message:

```
Layer is not valid : The layer file:///C:/Users/ABCDE/AppData/Local/Temp/QGIS3.HJlEUi?
delimiter=%09&delimiterType=regexp&xField=WP_Lat&yField=WP_Long is not a valid  layer
and can not be added to the map. Reason:
```

Looking at the QGIS Log Messages, under the "Delimited Text" tab I can see:

```
2020-01-15T18:39:48  WARNING  Errors in file C:/Users/ABCDE/AppData/Local/Temp/QGIS3.HJlEUi
2020-01-15T18:39:48  WARNING  X field is not defined in delimited text file
2020-01-15T18:39:48  WARNING  Y field is not defined in delimited text file
```

I have looked at the temporary file QGIS3.HJlEUi it appears to be a delimited text file in exactly the correct format:

```
WP_Lat  WP_Long

-15.765315  40.515876

-15.779443  40.534107

-15.816472  40.628185

-15.816369  40.611462

-15.816465  40.628178

-15.816469  40.628175
```

Can any one see what might be going wrong?

QGIS 3.8.3
eVis 1.1.0 (core plugin)
Windows 10

Comment: The `delimiter=%09` seems to expect horizontal tabs as delimiters.

Comment: the temporary file that eVis creates IS delimited by Horizontal Tabs (copy & paste into the original message made it look a bit odd)

Answer (score 1):

The eVis plugin has been removed from QGIS 3.14 and is no longer supported.

See final contribution at the end of this [GitHub post](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33848)